# Как получить случайный элемент из словаря в Python?

Tags: python, словари

```
people = {"person1": "1", "person2": "2", "person3": "3", "person4": "4"}
```

сделал так для примера

Comment: Словарь для этого не предназначен. Извлеките ключи или значения, сделайте choice

Comment: print(random.choice(list(people.values())))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете создать список из ключей словарья и с помощью библиотеки random выбрать случайный ключ и использовать ее:

```
import random

people = {"person1": "1", "person2": "2", "person3": "3", "person4": "4"}

people_keys_list = list(people.keys())
random_key = random.choice(people_keys_list)

# И обратится к значению по этому ключу

print(people[random_key])
```

Comment: Спасибо большое помогло

Comment: @Nadir можете нажать ответ полезен (стрелка вверх у моего ответа) и галочку. Заранее признателен

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
people = {"person1": "1", "person2": "2", "person3": "3", "person4": "4"}
key = random.choice(list(people.keys()))
print(people[key])
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]